# Fitting curve for exponential: $y = A - B\mathrm{e}^{-t/\tau}$

Tags: graphing-functions, exponential-function, regression

I have some data that follows a *saturation* or *charging* profile such as $y = A - B\mathrm{e}^{-t/\tau}$. To begin with, is there a proper name for this function? I have seen it many times, including: charging of capacitors, saturation of mixtures, and control systems, but I don't know what to call it, making it difficult to search for a solution.

I am not sure how I should go about this. I could brute force the calculation by choosing sets of three points, calculating the variables $A$, $B$, and $\tau$, then averaging the lot to get $\hat{y} = \bar{A} - \bar{B}\mathrm{e}^{-t/\bar{\tau}}$, but I assume that there is a better way.

Comment: What is your data?

Comment: It's energy of a system versus time. As time progresses, the system reaches a stead state value, similar to $A - B \mathrm{e}^{-t/\tau}$.

Comment: I mean, it is a large set of data?

Comment: Not overly large, about 10,000 data points per configuration (10 configurations).

Comment: Have you tried some computer algebra systems?

Comment: I'm working with Python and I would like to eliminate any external processing tools, especially non open source programs (e.g., Mathematica and Maple).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem of non-linear regession. The usual statistial softwares are able to compute some good approximations of the parameters, insofar you give an acceptable guess of the parameters to start an iterative process.

Another method which do not requires initial guess and which don't use an iterative process is described in the paper "Régressions et équations intégrales" published on Scribd : http://www.scribd.com/JJacquelin/documents (in French, but one have only to apply the easily understandable procedure page 17 in boxed text). The notations are different from yours : the function to be fitted is y=a+b*exp(c*x) where a, b, c are the parameters to be optimized. It requires a sufficiently large number of points (x,y) of the given data set to lead to a good fitting.

Comment: This looks very interesting! It seems my 10 years of French classes as a child might be more useful than I thought!

Comment: Jean, thank you very much! I was able to implement your approach and it seems to work very well. The example in your paper proved very helpful when I was tracking down a bug. Has this work been published anywhere?

Comment: @William: glad this help you ! There is no regular publication up to now. The publication on Sribd allows additions and extensions, since the topic is far to be completed.

Comment: @JJacquelin. May I ask : where are you ? Look my profile. I am very interested by your paper but I cannot access Scribd. Is there any way to get it ? Thanks et à bientôt.

Comment: @ Claude Leibovici : Connaissant vos références à Pau ( cfl-consultant...) je vous envoie l'article par e-mail.
 Bien cordialement, JJ.

Comment: @JJacquelin, your method has worked very well for me so far, but I recently encountered a problem. When I calculate the coefficients and plot the resulting function, it is obvious it is **not** the best (least squares) fit, e.g., https://www.dropbox.com/s/vmku6940x2hx6sw/controlFit.pdf, SSE = 13.2. However, if I tweak the "A" parameter, by multiplying it by 1.0001, the fit is much better, e.g., https://www.dropbox.com/s/mlitey8ksfwpu9f/tweakFit.pdf, SSE = 4.6. I thought I may have made an error in my implementation, but when I check it with a known function, it returns the correct values.

Comment: @ William : since where is no major discrepancy, the implementation is probably correct. The trouble comes probably from something else. It’s impossible to say without more information : drawings are not sufficient. I could check it if you give the input data set (on a file .txt format, or Excel,…)

Comment: @JJacquelin, if you have spare time and are interested in taking a look, here is a copy of some of the data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cv1761dwcseztqv/EPg50dp1.1pi1.dat. In the meantime I managed to use pythons scipy.optimize.curve_fit to minimize the residuals and fit the curve. The disadvantage of this method is that it requires an initial guess and exits when a tolerance is reached, whereas your method requires no guess and it not iterative.

Comment: @ William, sorry I cannot read correctly the file.dat : I obtain a series of numbers without separation between one to the others. There is more chance to be compatible if the format was .txt instead of .dat ; I am ready to test your data with my own soft and try to see where is the trouble. In any case, you could already use my method to compute an initial "guess" and then the soft "pythons..." for a final optimization.

Comment: @JJacquelin, Sorry about that, it's formatted with Linux "line returns", which are not recognized by Windows/Mac. I've converted it to three different formats, txt: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rce648lo5p0wzfz/data.txt, csv: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9kzzz3427ud2gyp/data.csv, and xls: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8mqbn99fs1v2af8/data.xls. I think you will have better luck with the csv and xls files. Thanks!

Comment: @ William : meanwhile I succeed to read your first data file. My computer program gives a very accurate fitting : In order to be able to attach the figure, I open a new answer. The computed values of the parameters are given on it. Since your result is not consistent with mine, there is certainely a bug somewhere in your implementation. I am confident that this will soon be solved.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with nonlinear regression is that "reasonable" estimates of the parameters must be provided as starting points.

Your equation, which is quite classical, presents interesting features : for $t=0$, the function value is $(A-B)$; at the steady state, the function value is $A$ . So, just by inspection of the plot of your data, you already have an idea of the values of these two parameters. The only problem left is $\tau$ : you can get it very simply looking for which approximate time (say $tm$) the function value is $(A-B/2)$ which corresponds to the mean value of your interval; this lead to $\tau= tm / log(2)$. Now you have your three "reasonable" estimates and you can start your nonlinear regression.

If you do not have the appropriate software, you have another solution since, if $\tau$ is fixed, the model becomes linear with respect to its parametrers. Then, for a given value of $\tau$, you can run standard linear regression; this means that, for each value of $\tau$, you have the value of the sum of squares; plot this sum of squares as a funtion of $\tau$ and look for its minimum. Refine the process as long as necessary.

There is one point I would also like to address here : least square procedures favor the points corresponding to largest $y$ values. If you want your data to be as correctly represented over the whole range, weighting is a good way. As a physicist, when I have to do this kind of work, I use to minimize the sum of the squares of relative errors.

Answer (score 1):

It's just the exponential function. The reason why you see it everywhere is because it's a solution for the differential equation of the same format. I.E. the examples you said all have the same differential equation that describes the system.

If you punch in the points in excel and use an exponential fit, you should get an accurate graph. If you know what A should be, you can also force fit the intercept such that it fits your assumption / data.

Comment: You are correct, they are all solutions to the same (form) DE; good point! I have tried using Excel; however, it is unable to fit such a function.

Comment: Interesting. You should be able to fit it using an exponential fit. If not, you can always take pairs of point like you said and calculate A & tau; then take the average of all the ones you calculated however that seems cumbersome.

Comment: I think the problem is that Excel fits to the function $Ae^{bt}$, but can not consider a separate term.

Comment: Subtracting 1 from all the $y$ values then negate them should get it into the format $y* = Ae^{bt}$, with $y*$ being $-(y-1)$.

Comment: I guess I should have been more general. I really want to model $y = A - Be^{-t/\tau}$.

Comment: Take a look at this page if you have access to MATLAB:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/exponential.html
Setting $b$ to 0 for the 2nd equation would result in the model $A - Ce^{-dt}$

Answer (score 1):

The data set provided by William has a very low scatter and the points are numerous (500) and well distributed. As a consequence, the method of "regression with integral equation" gives a very accurate result (attachment : points in black, fitted curve in red)

[image]

Comment: I went back and re-wrote the regression function, and all is well now. It turned out I had two small mistakes. For some reason the function had been working great for the previous data sets, but this one cause errors. Thanks again!